# Good C header style

Tags: c, coding-style, header-files

My C headers usually resemble the following style to avoid multiple inclusion:

```
#ifndef <FILENAME>_H
#define <FILENAME>_H

// define public data structures / prototypes, macros etc.

#endif  /* !<FILENAME>_H */
```

However, in his [Notes on Programming in C](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/pikestyle.html), Rob Pike makes the following argument about header files:

> There's a little dance involving `#ifdef`'s that can prevent a file being read twice, but it's usually done wrong in practice - the `#ifdef`'s are in the file itself, not the file that includes it.  The result is often thousands of needless lines of code passing through the lexical analyzer, which is (in good compilers) the most expensive phase.

On the one hand, Pike is the only programmer I actually admire. On the other hand, putting several `#ifdef`s in multiple source files instead of putting one `#ifdef` in a single header file feels needlessly awkward.

What is the best way to handle the problem of multiple inclusion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my opinion, use the method that requires less of your time (which likely means putting the #ifdefs in the header files).  I don't really mind if the compiler has to work harder if my resulting code is cleaner.  If, perhaps, you are working on a multi-million line code base that you constantly have to fully rebuild, maybe the extra savings is worth it.  But in most cases, I suspect that the extra cost is not usually noticeable.

Comment: I find this answer very useful. Funny thing is that I agree in a more ironic way: if the computer can do my job, why I'll do it? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Keep doing what you do - It's clear, less bug-prone, and well known by compiler writers, so not as inefficient as it maybe was a decade or two ago.

You could use the non-standard `#pragma once` - If you search, there's probably at least a bookshelf's worth of include guards vs pragma once discussion, so I'm not going to recommend one over the other.

Comment: If gcc didn't suck, it would detect the standard idiom the first time the header was included, remember the filename, and ignore all future requests to include that filename. This is purely a case of compiler laziness.

Comment: @R. It still doesn't? I'd have thought every major compiler would have this a decade ago. Then again, reading a file twice isn't really the resource hog it was in 89 when Pike wrote those notes.

Comment: @R..: it claims to do so - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html. However, there are some restrictions that it uses to ensure the optimization is valid, and there could be false negatives where the restrictions are broken, but nevertheless the optimization would be valid in that case.

Comment: Reading it twice is a resource hog. Just a single syscall takes more time, on modern machines, than parsing a small header file.

Answer (score 5):

Pike wrote some more about it in https://talks.golang.org/2012/splash.article:

> In 1984, a compilation of `ps.c`, the source to the Unix ps command, was
>   observed to `#include <sys/stat.h>` 37 times by the time all the
>   preprocessing had been done. Even though the contents are discarded 36
>   times while doing so, most C implementations would open the file, read
>   it, and scan it all 37 times. Without great cleverness, in fact, that
>   behavior is required by the potentially complex macro semantics of the
>   C preprocessor.

Compilers have become quite clever since: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html, so this is less of an issue now.

> The construction of a single C++ binary at Google can open and read
>   hundreds of individual header files tens of thousands of times. In
>   2007, build engineers at Google instrumented the compilation of a
>   major Google binary. The file contained about two thousand files that,
>   if simply concatenated together, totaled 4.2 megabytes. By the time
>   the #includes had been expanded, over 8 gigabytes were being delivered
>   to the input of the compiler, a blow-up of 2000 bytes for every C++
>   source byte.
>
> As another data point, in 2003 Google's build system was moved from a
>   single Makefile to a per-directory design with better-managed, more
>   explicit dependencies. A typical binary shrank about 40% in file size,
>   just from having more accurate dependencies recorded. Even so, the
>   properties of C++ (or C for that matter) make it impractical to verify
>   those dependencies automatically, and today we still do not have an
>   accurate understanding of the dependency requirements of large Google
>   C++ binaries.

The point about binary sizes is still relevant. Compilers (linkers) are quite conservative regarding stripping unused symbols. [How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/c-c-gcc-ld-remove-unused-symbols)

> In Plan 9, header files were forbidden from containing further
>   `#include` clauses; all `#includes` were required to be in the top-level C file. This required some discipline, of course—the programmer was
>   required to list the necessary dependencies exactly once, in the
>   correct order—but documentation helped and in practice it worked very
>   well.

This is a possible solution. Another possiblity is to have a tool that manages the includes for you, for example [MakeDeps](https://github.com/russellallen/self/blob/871b7ce9289b6693bc04473941752379e4027d0d/vm/build_support/makeDeps.cpp).

There is also unity builds, sometimes called SCU, single compilation unit builds. There are tools to help manage that, like https://github.com/sakra/cotire

Using a build system that optimizes for the speed of incremental compilation can be advantageous too. I am talking about Google's Bazel and similar. It does not protect you from a change in a header file that is included in a large number of other files, though.

Finally, there is a proposal for C++ modules in the works, great stuff https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!forum/modules. See also [What exactly are C++ modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693950/what-exactly-are-c-modules)

Comment: As seen in the first paragraph in your second quote, in as late as 2007 the problem is still prominent. If only more recent benchmarks are available.

Comment: According to https://web.archive.org/web/20021218032155/http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html, GCC could do the Multiple-Include Optimization already in late 2002. I wonder what compiler was Google using  using in 2007.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're currently doing it is the common way. Pike's method cuts a bit on compilation time, but with modern compilers probably not very much (when Pike wrote his notes, compilers weren't optimizer-bound), it clutters modules and its bug-prone.

You could still cut on multi-inclusion by not including headers from headers, but instead documenting them with "include `<foodefs.h>` before including this header."

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you put them in the source-file itself. No need to complain about some thousand needless parsed lines of code with actual PCs.

Additionally - it is far more work and source if you check every single header in every source-file that includes the header.

And you would have to handle your header-files different from default- and other third-party-headers.

Answer (score 1):

He may have had an argument the time he was writing this. Nowadays decent compilers are clever enough to handle this well.

Comment: @R., Hm, reference, no I don't have. I read that not too long time ago here on SO though, that include guards are treated by gcc equivalent to `#pragma once`. And BTW the lexical parsing of `#ifdef` to first see what of a file has to be parsed for real should not be too difficult, no? In any case, I never found for me that *this* was a bottleneck when compiling large code. I often do precompilation with `-E` to see what the preprocessing phase produces and this is not measurable by human eye.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your approach - as others have commented, its clearer, self-documenting, and lower maintenance.

My theory on why Rob Pike might have suggested his approach: He's talking about C, not C++.

In C++, if you have a lot of classes and you are declaring each one in its own header file, then you'll have a lot of header files. C doesn't really provide this kind of fine-grained structure (I don't recall seeing many single-struct C header files), and .h/.c file-pairs *tend* to be larger and contain something like a module or a subsystem. So, fewer header files. In that scenario Rob Pike's approach might work. But I don't see it as suitable for non-trivial C++ programs.